# Get autoplayed file path (file with arbitrary extension)

Tags: c#

I have defined new extension(.abc) in windows registry by using following instructions:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\abcApp_V1\shell\open\command]
@="c:\abcApp.exe \"%1\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.abc]
@="abcApp_V1"
```

This works properly and now each file with .abc extension opens the abcApp.exe program.

How could I get the file's path (**the file with .abc extension** which is double clicked!) in my **abcApp** program?

Comment: Are you asking how to get your app's command-line parameters?

Comment: I think this could be my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joe White for the comment.
This is my answer:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileS = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        MessageBox.Show(fileS[1]);
    }
```